# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, visual-studio-2005

I have seen many object reference not set to an instance of an object questions, but I couldn't find my scenario in any.

I have a combo box named `comboBox1`. While form loads I have code to populate combobox:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the
        // 'tenderDBDataSet.tbl_Tender_To_Details' table.
        // You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT 
            tbl_Tender_To_Details.To_Name, tbl_Tender_To_Details.To_Address1, 
            tbl_Tender_To_Details.To_Address2, 
            tbl_Tender_To_Details.To_City, tbl_Tender_To_Details.To_PinCode "+
            "FROM tbl_Tender_To_Details "+
            "WHERE to_Name IS NOT NULL ", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["To_Name"]);
                // listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                // MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
```

The `MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());` line shows:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object for combo box".

But my surprise is the value at index 0 is set to combo box while form loads after this object reference msg box.

Comment: get the combobox item count after the while loop, it will tell many of the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try put this statement at page load and make sure the combobox has loaded with items or not??

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

if you are using winforms then try put that statement in initializecomponent() function

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Hi errorstacks, thanks for reply.. but i have put this statement at form load only.... how do i add in page load

Comment: @shanmugamgsn u have tagged asp.net also , so i am thinking of that you are using asp.net but ,in code you have mentioned combobox ....

Comment: sorry i will remove asp.net tag. i'm using visual studio 2005 C#. Windows application only not web application

Comment: @shanmugamgsn put a break point at this line comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["To_Name"]); and try in debug mode and check whether items are added to combobox or not...

Comment: Hi i tried debugging. i found out error at catch block.  catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

Comment: hey sorry guys error was in  MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: @shanmugamgsn the problem is combobox  empty, the items are not added to the  combobox.....

Comment: but i can see the items listed in combo box.. but if i give this MessageBox.Show this error is thrown.

Comment: just a msg box with the value selected in combo box

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not to set the selected index to 0 explicitly. It is 0 by default. There are chances that nothing is loaded from database after executing the reader and hence the DataSource of combobox is null. In that scenario, if you try to set the selected index to 0, null reference exception would be thrown as framework tries to retrieve the first item in data source which is null. In this scenario, your selected index should be -1.

So, if you want the selected index to be the first item in the list, I would not set the selected item explicitly. That is the default behavior for combobox.

Comment: Hi Suhas, but as you say if i remove SelectedIndex=0 line i'm getting empty Combobox.. but i can see those items items below... is there any way?

Comment: @shanmugamgsn if you put selectindex = -1 the combobox fill with items and does not show any item in this property at the formload (i.e) combobox.Text =0

Comment: sorry error was in  MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you try to use a debugger to check whether the reader is actually putting anything?

I noticed that you capitalised "To_Name" in the reader but not in the where clause - are you sure its not case-sensitive?

Secondly, since you're working with databases, an easier method would be to return the db results the function into a DataTable and then use Databinding.

Comment: sorry error was in  MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
... could you say wat it is

Comment: If its an object reference exception, it means the SelectedValue in comboBox1 is null. This means that probably the box is empty.

Learn to use the debugger. Trace the program and see what exactly is in the comboBox.Items before that triggers.

Comment: What I mean is this: Add a breakpoint in the line exactly after the add. Watch combobox1.Items. At each loop iteration, see if the values are changing. I personally think its the case sensitivity thing, but this way we'll find out. Or the reader is returning 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object for combo box".

Means one or two things normally.
combobox not initialized to null;
or combobox not initalized to new

ComboBox combobox = null;
then inside of the try set the combobox variable to an instance of new like the following 
Try
{
  combobox = new Combobox();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error message when trying to use `.SelectedValue`. I changed it to `.SelectedItem` and the error went away. Example:

```
string selection = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

### try this instead

```
    if (ComboWeeks.SelectedItem as WeeksTable is null)  
 return;
```

this is work for me

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).